# Scheduled e-mails sent with wrong encoding

Tags: civimail, cron

Crossposting from https://chat.civicrm.org town-square channel in case anyone here has seen this possible bug.

Hey all - upgrade to 5.56.0 on WP seems to have introduced a bug in scheduled mail via cron. Test e-mails work fine but all e-mail sent via the scheduler comes through with misinterpreted encoding like:

--=_001d42344260fbe283874768193e6dd0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

DearÂ Geof Newton,

The From: address also gets munged - anyone else seeing a similar issue or worked through a fix?

Comment: I asked a followup question in town-square chat: Is that coming from a token - check your greeting token settings.

Comment: Problem resolved - it seems to have been an issue with the latest FlexMailer version that was delivered with 5.56.0. I disabled FlexMailer and re-enabled and it cleared up the encoding glitch.

Comment: I take that back - FlexMailer subsequently caused the site to error; removed and reinstalled FlexMailer extension, fully reinstalled the 5.56.0 release, tried BAO vs. Flex engines - scheduled e-mails are still incorrectly encoded and have a bad From: address.

Comment: Updated mail settings to use SMTP instead of mail() and tokens, HTML and in-line images are rendered correctly. Apparently the FlexMailer integration with the localhost mail function isn't working correctly?